# How to persist a suggester in lucene?

Tags: java, lucene, persist

I want to persist a BlendedInfixSuggester in lucene, after calling `suggester.build(dictionary);`

I'm trying to use the store method avaliable in BlendedInfixSuggester, but it fails to succeed.

```
final OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("suggester.dat"));
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
boolean success = suggester.store(dos); //success = false
```

Building a suggester may take long if the dictionary is large. But I can't find anywhere how to persist one. The store method returns false.. (unsuccess). The file is created, but remains with 0Bytes.

I also tried supplying an existing directory path, because the documentation says "Persists the constructed lookup data to a directory" in the method description. However, I get an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: suggester (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at learnlucene.AutoSuggester.main(AutoSuggester.java:98)
Java Result: 1
```

I'm pretty sure I have permissions on that folder, so this exception seems to suggest a file was expected. But nothing really works.

Comment: What error do you get when trying to persist it? The docs say store() "Persists the constructed lookup data to a directory." but you're trying to output to a file

Comment: @bcoughlan You are right, I had tested it with a directory but with no success. I updated the question.

Comment: Does that directory exist? Try it with the full path

Comment: @bcoughlan It does. I did, same thing. Have you haver persisted a Lookup instance?

Comment: Nope I was just trying the obvious solutions. The Lucene users mailing list may be a better resource.